# Why on ECS I got certbot: error: unrecognized arguments?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs, lets-encrypt

Why I got this error:

```
[ec2-user@ip-00-0-0-000 ~]$ docker logs 8cb180e9b3b6
usage:
  certbot [SUBCOMMAND] [options] [-d DOMAIN] [-d DOMAIN] ...

Certbot can obtain and install HTTPS/TLS/SSL certificates.  By default,
it will attempt to use a webserver both for obtaining and installing the
certificate.
certbot: error: unrecognized arguments: help all
```

on `certbot/certbot:latest` image on ecs?

Did I miss something in my `docker-compose.yml` file?

```
version: '3'

services:
 certbot:
    image: certbot/certbot:latest
    # ports:
    # - '80:80'
    command:
      - 'help all'
    volumes:
      - /docker-volumes/etc/letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt
      - /docker-volumes/var/lib/letsencrypt:/var/lib/letsencrypt
      - /docker/letsencrypt-docker-nginx/src/letsencrypt/letsencrypt-site:/data/letsencrypt
      - /docker-volumes/var/log/letsencrypt:/var/log/letsencrypt"
```

I have try in command section to put but I got same message:

```
-'certbot certonly --webroot --email mydomain@gmail.com -d www.mydomain.net -d mydomain.net --agree-tos --no-eff-email --webroot-path=/data/letsencrypt'
```

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else that stumbles across this, whilst you can get away with this locally; ECS is slightly different even if it can take what looks like a regular compose file.

The task definition expects it to be a comma separated list of values. So you would need to pass it like

```
command:
  - 'help'
  - 'all'
```